# Unexpected Token "#" For a login

Tags: angular

Im getting this: Unexpected token # at column 7 in [login(#userName.value, #userPassword.value)]

Now I know its caused by

```
<div class="displayTable">
   <div class="displayTableCell">
    <div class="formGroup">
    <input type="text" class="formControl" placeholder="Username" #userName required>
    </div>

    <div class="formGroup">
    <input type="password" class="formControl" placeholder="Password" #userPassword required>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn googleBtn" value="Log In" (click)="login(#userName.value, #userPassword.value)"></button>
    <a routerLink="register" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My function call but im following a little tutorial learning but I dont understand why I cant use the # to identify input fields is there a import im missing or something?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use userName and userPassword without # in login

```
 (click)="login(userName.value, userPassword.value)"
```

Comment: Oh wow, wait so after u use the identifier u dont need to keep the # to identify it again in any pass ins?

Comment: # is for reference declaration afterward you can use it by reference name only

Comment: Ah thats a interesting way of doing it thank you!